# F# equivalent of SortedDictionary from C#

Tags: f#

new to F#
i need to store a bunch of lists of objects according to a float number where the collection of lists are sorted according to the float number. I know in C# i would use

```
SortedDictionary<float, List<obj>>
```

as the implementation is a red black tree, allowing for log(n) insert and search. But whats the best way to attack the situation in F#. I attempted to use SortedDitionary but i can't refer to SortedDictionary[int] to find the value so it renders it as useless essentially (i could be doing it wrong).

thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is

```
sorteddictionary.[int]
```

then it works as you would expect

Comment: oh thanks! can you explain why possibly? sorry if its obvious

Comment: @Abstract - The F# array access syntax needs a `.` - not quite sure why, it is the same for arrays, lists etc.  Also, if this is correct please accept the answer

Comment: @JohnPalmer: I think it is to avoid the potential confusion between `a[0]`, indexing `a` with `0`, and `a [0]`, `a` followed by `[0]`. Either from a readability or parsing standpoint.

Comment: I remember reading back in the pre-2.0 days that they intended to support the "dotless" syntax, i.e. it is a parsing issue as @Guvante first suggested vs. a readability issue.

Answer (score 1):

The first thig to do is read Okasaki's book [Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Purely-Functional-Structures-Chris-Okasaki/dp/0521663504)

It has ML implementations that may help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sorteddictionary.[int]` as John Palmer already said but it may be worth pointing out that the F# standard library includes a purely functional sorted dictionary collection called `Map`.